# How to change the color of toggle button in multi-select-combo-box Vaadin component?

Tags: css, vaadin

So I'm using the Vaddin multi select combo box in `filter.ts` like so:

```
        <vaadin-multi-select-combo-box
          required
          placeholder="Select countries to visit"
          item-label-path="name"
          item-id-path="code"
          .items="${this.items}"
        >
          <div slot="error-message">Please select at least one country</div>
        </vaadin-multi-select-combo-box>
```

And I'm trying to change the toggle button color like this in the same file:

```
  static styles = css`

     :host::part(toggle-button)::before {
       color: yellow;
     }

  `;
```

Which is the right selector as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

But the color of the toggle button is not changing:

[image]

It's the same grey as it was before.

what is the correct way of changing the toggle button color?

Comment: Not sure why Chrome shows that selector as matching the element. It might be a bug in the Chrome dev tools, as that `:host::part()` selector should not match anything.

Answer (score 3):

The selector you are using targets `:host`, which means the host element of the shadow root that contains the styles, which means the styles would have to be within the shadow DOM of the combo box itself for that to work.

Instead you should target the component's tag name and the respective part name:

```css
vaadin-multi-select-combo-box::part(toggle-button) {
  ...
}
```

Edit: See also the component's styling documentation which lists all available selectors: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/multi-select-combo-box/styling

Edit: [Example on Lit playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG48aGVhZD5cbiAgPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPVwibW9kdWxlXCIgc3JjPVwiLi9leGFtcGxlLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPGNvbWJvLWV4YW1wbGU-PC9jb21iby1leGFtcGxlPlxuPC9ib2R5PlxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoicGFja2FnZS5qc29uIiwiY29udGVudCI6IntcbiAgXCJkZXBlbmRlbmNpZXNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwibGl0XCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJAbGl0L3JlYWN0aXZlLWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMS4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjMuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtaHRtbFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiXG4gIH1cbn0iLCJoaWRkZW4iOnRydWV9XQ)

Comment: I tried this solution both in the static styles and the global styles but it doesn't work. I also checked out the link you sent for styles which is the same as you said. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure, might be something else in your setup. I've added a simple example on Lit playground to my answer if that helps.

Comment: Thank you I saw the example. Now I'm sure I'm doing it correctly. Gotta find the culprit.